# Trouble getting a color in Photoshop to show correctly in my browser

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, balance

My website has a background color of `#EEEEEE` `(238,238,238)`. I have an image with a light grey background I want to blend with this background. In Photoshop I used brightness adjustment to get `(238,238,238)`. But when I put the image on my site it shows as `#EEEDEE`, so it doesn't blend nicely, and the difference is visible. I played with the magenta/green settings of Color Balance, but I never seem to get `#EEEEEE` in my browser, it's either `#EEEDEE` or `#EEEFEE`.
I already switched from a `.jpg` file to a `.png` file.

How can I create the right color for my browser?

Comment: Try setting the color mode to Monitor RGB and unchecking "Proof Colors".  The adjust your colors and save.

Comment: @mdesdev - web safe colors, really?! Are we going back to the 1990s? There are *no* computers nowadays whose display is limited to a 256-color palette. (Besides, IIRC web safe colors don't include grays)